# lexikJWTAuthentication bundle Extending authenticator Call to a member function extract() on null when

Tags: php, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle, authenticator

Im using lexikJWTAuthenticationbundle to make a JWT authentication in my webservice. Everything works good but I want to override the authenticator to add further control especially controlling if the token sent to mee and its informations: header, signature are correct. Im following the documentation of the bundle about this.
https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/2.x/Resources/doc/6-extending-jwt-authenticator.md

But when i try to overwrite the function getCredentials i cannot get the TokenExtracor and i have this error in my logs.

"Call to a member function extract() on null" at vendor/lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle/Security/Guard/JWTTokenAuthenticator.php line 79 {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function extract() on null at vendor/lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle/Security/Guard/JWTTokenAuthenticator.php:79)"}"

for now im just trying to overwirte one function to see if it just works fine without changing anything to it.

Here is the code of my CustomAuthenticator.

```
<?php
namespace App\Security\Guard;

use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Guard\JWTTokenAuthenticator as BaseAuthenticator;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\TokenExtractor\AuthorizationHeaderTokenExtractor; 
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\TokenExtractor\TokenExtractorInterface; 
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\TokenExtractor\QueryParameterTokenExtractor; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticationJWTUserToken;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Exception\InvalidTokenException;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Exception\JWTDecodeFailureException;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Exception\ExpiredTokenException;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTTokenManagerInterface;

class JWTTokenAuthenticator extends BaseAuthenticator
{  

    /**
     * @var JWTTokenManagerInterface
     */
    private $jwtManager;

    public function __construct(
        JWTTokenManagerInterface $jwtManager
    ) {
        $this->jwtManager = $jwtManager;
    }
    /**
     * Returns a decoded JWT token extracted from a request.
     *
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @return PreAuthenticationJWTUserTokenInterface
     *
     * @throws InvalidTokenException If an error occur while decoding the token
     * @throws ExpiredTokenException If the request token is expired
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $tokenExtractor = parent::getTokenExtractor();


        if (!$tokenExtractor instanceof TokenExtractorInterface) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Method "%s::getTokenExtractor()" must return an instance of "%s".', __CLASS__, TokenExtractorInterface::class));
        }

        if (false === ($jsonWebToken = $tokenExtractor->extract($request))) {
            return;
        }

        $preAuthToken = new PreAuthenticationJWTUserToken($jsonWebToken);

        try {
            if (!$payload = $this->jwtManager->decode($preAuthToken)) {
                throw new InvalidTokenException('Invalid JWT Token');
            }

            $preAuthToken->setPayload($payload);
        } catch (JWTDecodeFailureException $e) {
            if (JWTDecodeFailureException::EXPIRED_TOKEN === $e->getReason()) {
                $expiredTokenException = new ExpiredTokenException();
                $expiredTokenException->setToken($preAuthToken);
                throw $expiredTokenException;
            }

            throw new InvalidTokenException('Invalid JWT Token', 0, $e);
        }

        return $preAuthToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check e.g. https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/743

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me a lot. The problem was that the attributes of the class in the bundle where private instead of protected. Thus, we couldn't access to them.